# triggers in mysql with timestamps

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have a main table like this ill be getting values for every one minute,here i want to use triggers to calculate every hour data automatically.

```
timestamps             energy
2014/11/3 04:00        10
2014/11/3 04:01        20
2014/11/3 04:02        30
2014/11/3 04:03        40
2014/11/3 04:04        50
2014/11/3 04:05        60
```

my output should be like this

```
time stamp             energy
2014/11/3 04:05        210
```

my code

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT( HOUR(timestamp), ' to ', CONCAT( HOUR(timestamp), ':05:00' ) ) as time_frame,
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  temp
GROUP BY 
  DATE(timestamp), 
  HOUR(timestamp)
```

i want to use triggers

Comment: What do you mean by `i want to use triggers` ? Trigger can execute only in case of insert/update/delete it can not run by itself.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, ill receive data for every minute continuously,here after the insertion of one hour data i have to sum all the one hour data and store it in separate table..i want to know that whether it can be done using triggers.

Comment: Well no trigger cant handle it since you want it to happen every hour I would suggest to use some sort of cronjob and then execute it every hour to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hourly` (
  `d` date NOT NULL,
  `h` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`d`,`h`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main` (
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `cache_sum_hourly`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `cache_sum_hourly` AFTER INSERT ON `main`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO hourly (d,h,value) VALUES (
DATE(NEW.timestamp),
HOUR(NEW.timestamp),
NEW.value )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hourly.value=hourly.value+NEW.value;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

But I am not sure how is this really needed. Normally, you should be able to count it just from main table.

Comment: this code works well, i my code data is interupted for few seconds, how can i use triggers to group hour for past data.

Comment: No, triggers are automated reactions to what happened right now. To process past, you simply process it. `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE ...(filter said old data)... ON DUPLICATE KEY ...`